# Как удалить динамический массив, возвращаемый функцией?

Tags: c++, c

Есть функция для создания массива:

```
unsigned short** addArray(unsigned short raw, unsigned short col) {
    unsigned short** Array = new unsigned short* [raw];
    for (unsigned short index = 0; index < raw; ++index) {
        Array[index] = new unsigned short [col];
    }
return Array;
}
```

Она не принимает массив, но возвращает массив, созданный new. Как я понимаю, после возвращения массива, я теряю доступ к блоку памяти с массивом Array и не могу его удалить.

*Может быть понадобится функция удаления:*

```
void delArray(unsigned short** Array, unsigned short raw) {
    for (unsigned short index = 0; index < raw; ++index) {
        delete[] Array[index];
    }
    delete[] Array;
}
```

Функция в main:

```
#include <conio.h>

#define Raw 12
#define Col 13

unsigned short** addArray(unsigned short raw, unsigned short col);
void delArray(unsigned short** Array, unsigned short raw);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     unsigned short** Arr = addArray(Raw, Col);
     delArray(Arr, Raw);
     _getch();
}

unsigned short** addArray(unsigned short raw, unsigned short col) {
    unsigned short** Array = new unsigned short* [raw];
    for (unsigned short index = 0; index < raw; ++index) {
        Array[index] = new unsigned short [col];
    }
return Array;
}

void delArray(unsigned short** Array, unsigned short raw) {
    for (unsigned short index = 0; index < raw; ++index) {
        delete[] Array[index];
    }
    delete[] Array;
}
```

Было бы интересно узнать другие пути решения без заполнения памяти! Спасибо

Comment: Вы *не можете*  удалять то, что возвращаете, так как вызывающий код будет это использовать.

Comment: Если есть другие варианты, готов принять.
Поправьте, если ошибаюсь, тег си здесь будет уместен. Спасибо

Comment: Что вы понимаете под "*без заполнения памяти*"?

Comment: Без заполнения памяти, то есть без создания блоков, к которым можно потерять доступ.

Comment: Код написан на Си, думаю ему соответствует

Comment: Можно возвращать `std::unique_ptr`, он сам удалится когда станет не нужен, и функция будет выглядеть примерно так `auto myfunc(...)`, внутри создать с помощью `auto a = std::make_unique<..>(size)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Как я понимаю, после возвращения массива, я теряю доступ к блоку памяти с массивом Array и не могу его удалить.

Ну почему же? Вы его сохраняете в какой-то переменной, работаете, потом удаляете...

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     unsigned short** Arr = addArray(Row, Col);
     // Работа с Arr
     delArray(Arr,Row);
}
```

Вполне годится :)

Но раз у вас C++ - то есть варианты

```
array<array<int,Row>,Col> Arr;
```

если `Row` и `Col` известны во время компиляции, или

```
vector<vector<int>>
```

Если размеры известны во время выполнения или меняются.

Comment: Да, я Вас понял. Значит массив Arr занимает память, выделенную под unsigned short** Array = new unsigned short* [raw]; И после функции Array не оставляет память) Спасибо, что помогли понять!

Comment: @Илья, это происходит потому, что массив создаётся в динамической памяти, а не на стеке функции.

Comment: Стоп-стоп-стоп! Нет, `Arr` **указывает** на выделенную память. В функции где-то в куче выделяется память, указатель на которую возвращается из функции. А потом, после работы с ней, другая функция ее освобождает. Ну, как аналог - `malloc/free`.

Comment: @Harry, Да мы с вами говорим об одном: "И после функции Array не оставляет память" - верно, Array не остался пустым указателем, а указатель Arr ссылается на ячейку указателя Array.

Comment: @PREACHER, `unique_ptr` или `vector` вас спасет от утечек памяти :) остальное требует ручного удаления